# How can i send empty terminal output from server to client?

Tags: python, linux, client-server

I'm trying to make a send linux command from client to server and resend server output to client. I can send all command to server and they are working in server side but when i send command like a "mkdir, rmdir etc." these commands are working in server side but client can't receive the terminal output message. I think it is because of actually there is no output message yet, my client side is stuck and i have to restart it.

client side:

```
    while True: 
 # message sent to server 

        s.send(message.encode('ascii')) 
        # messaga received from server 

        data = s.recv(1024) 
   # print the received message 
        # here it would be a reverse of sent message

        print('Received from the server :',str(data.decode('ascii'))) 
        # ask the client whether he wants to continue 

        ans = input('\nDo you want to continue(y/n) :') 
        if ans == 'y':
            message = input("enter message")
            continue
        else: 
            break

    # close the connection 
    s.close()
```

server side:

```
while True:

        # data received from client

        data = c.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            print('Bye')
            break
        try:
            data_o = subprocess.check_output(data, shell=True)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            c.send(b'failed\n')
            print(e.output)
        #data_o = subprocess.Popen(["echo", data], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

        print(type(data_o))
        c.send(data_o)
```

example output:
[image]

Thanks for your helps

Comment: I found a similar question. Please check this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/29370/how-to-check-if-a-command-succeeded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the output is a bytes object of length 0, nothing at all is sent, but your client keeps waiting for an answer. A simple solution would be to just send a string like "no output was given".
To prevent a confusion incase the command `echo no output was given` is sent, you could add a prefix to each response.

something like this:

```
if data[0:prefix_len]== success_prefix:
    print(data[prefix_len:]
elif data[0:prefix_len] == empty_prefix:
    print("command had no output")
```